# Second TOC at the end of the document

Tags: table-of-contents, report

I am trying to create a document with 2 TOC's - one at the beginning of the document, and one at the end. However, the second TOC has only the title.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Part 1}
\part{Part 2}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

[image: First TOC]

[image: Second TOC]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of the `shorttoc` package and a correctly chose value of the second argument (`depth`), you can get a document that has two table of contents:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\begin{document}
\shorttableofcontents{Contents}{2}
\part{Part 1}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\part{Part 2}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```